# How to make a black background transition on Slick carousel?

Tags: javascript, css, carousel, slick.js

I'm trying to emulate [this black/dark transition](http://www.jeannouvel.com/). It looks like a linear animation, but in between each slide there is about 1 second or so of just pure black.

How could I emulate this with Slick slider?

```
$('.slider').slick({
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      dots: false,
      prevArrow: false,
      nextArrow: false,
      useTransform: true,
      cssEase: 'linear',
      speed: 4000,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 4000,
      fade: true,
      infinite: true
    });
```

I've set the background as black but the opacity doesn't seem to show the background, rather it just transitions into the next slide.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

On the example site you added, this is achieved by using the class `homeSlider` (which is a different library as far as I am aware) that uses:

```
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 50rem;
height: 100vh;
background-color: #000; // Sets background colour here
```

Using Slick, you can set the the `background-color: black` on the class `.slick-track`. Here is a fiddle that I demonstrate this on: https://jsfiddle.net/b5bqk68j/4883/

Comment: I tried that but its not coming as per the website as he mentioned above http://www.jeannouvel.com/

Comment: Ok sure. What's happening when you add `background-color: black` to the `.slick-track` class? Is it not styling the fade at all?

Comment: am not getting that much fade in effect. In that website they using

-webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s 1s cubic-bezier(.455,.03,.515,.955) both;
    -o-animation: fadeIn 1s 1s cubic-bezier(.455,.03,.515,.955) both;
    animation: fadeIn 1s 1s cubic-bezier(.455,.03,.515,.955) both;
for next slide. fade out for current slide

Comment: Hi, thanks for this but - yes it doesn't work for me like the jeanouvel.com site - yours fades into a grey colour but doesn't go fully black. How could I make it go fully black?